# Нет доступа к расоположению файла после его загрузки через php

Tags: windows, apache, php

Здравствуйте. Не могу открыть изображение после того как загружаю его через php. Делаю сайт на локальной машине в 8-й винде. Когда в нужную папку (localhost/site/img) просто помещаю изображение, то оно открывается без проблем. После того как загружаю в эту же папку изображение через php, то открыть это изображение уже не получается и винда выдает след. сообщение: "Средство просмотра фотографий не может открыть это изображение, так как отсутствует разрешение на доступ к расположению файла". Браузер также не может открыть это изображение. При этом админом и владельцем папки являюсь я, права стоят на все действия (полный доступ). В чем проблема и как её решить?

Спасибо.

Comment: В винде более хитрая система прав, чем в юниксах, там недостаточно просто являться владельцем, нужны именно права на чтение файла (свойства файла -> безопасность). В юниксах, в принципе, тоже можно снять бит чтения для владельца.

Comment: права стоят абсолютно на все (полный доступ), при этом проблема остается

Comment: попробуй после загрузки ставить права на картинку 777

Comment: проблема в том что права на файл другие, апач запускается под собственным пользователем. и да, руткод или биткод